# Code signing, do I need to generate a keystore?

Tags: java, code-signing, signing, jar-signing

I am trying sign an app using keytool, but I dont have a keystore file.

Do I need to generate this file myself or should I receive it from from code signing authority ? 
If so what files do I require to generate a keystore file ?

Thanks

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/JAR_Signing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key store is a database for your keys. The process of "signing" an app (e.g. with jarsigner) is roughly the following:

1. You create a private/public key pair with keytool.
2. You then create a CSR (certificate signing request)
3. A CA (certification authority) processes your request and gives you a certificate.
4. You have to import the CA response into your keystore.

You may create self signed certificate to get a feeling of the process. You may use openssl.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer under your fingertips... keytool is your friend...

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html

Keystore Creation

A keystore is created whenever you use a -genkey, -import, or -identitydb command to add data to a keystore that doesn't yet exist.
More specifically, if you specify, in the -keystore option, a keystore that doesn't yet exist, that keystore will be created.

If you don't specify a -keystore option, the default keystore is a file named .keystore in your home directory. If that file does not yet exist, it will be created.